# C++ Vector of coordinates from .xyz file

Tags: c++, coordinates

I am a newb and I am trying to read a .xyz file into a vector. Here is the code I am workin on:

```
#include <inq/inq.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  using namespace inq;
  using namespace inq::magnitude;

  input::environment env(argc, argv);
  auto comm = boost::mpi3::environment::get_world_instance();

  auto distance = 2.5_angstrom;

  std::ifstream nos("zr_50_atoms.xyz");
  std::vector<input::atom> atoms;
  std::string word;
  float x,y,z;
  while (nos >> word >> x >> y >> z)
  {
    atoms.push_back("word" | input::coord(x, y, z));
  }
  //atoms.push_back("Zr" | input::coord(0.0_angstrom, 0.0_angstrom, 0.0_angstrom));
  //atoms.push_back("Zr" | input::coord(0.0_angstrom, 0.0_angstrom, distance));

  auto length = 10.0_angstrom;
  auto box = input::cell::cubic(length);

  systems::ions ions(box, atoms);

  systems::electrons electrons(comm, ions, input::basis::cutoff_energy(10.0_Ha));
  ground_state::initial_guess(ions, electrons);

  auto result = ground_state::calculate(ions, electrons, input::interaction::pbe(), input::scf::scf_steps(1000));

  std::cout << "E = " << result.energy.total() << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

I am trying to read a .xyz coordinate file which looks like this:

```
Zr    0.000000    1.870038    2.586000
Zr   12.956000    1.870038    2.586000
Zr    1.619500    4.675094    2.586000
Zr    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
```

The vector needs to be in this particular format:

```
atoms.push_back("Zr" | input::coord(0.0_angstrom, 0.0_angstrom, 0.0_angstrom));
```

Now my question is how do I add the units ("_angstrom") to each of my coordinates? Also is there a better way accomplish the task?

Thank you for you help!

Comment: If you read these numbers from a file, they are not literals and you cannot "add the units". Instead, you should convert them to the appropriate type (which is probably a part of the library you're working with).

Comment: Adding a non-numeric subscript is a bad idea. Instead, if you need to specify units within a data file, add a single, specific designation (e.g.. first line, etc..) that provides the units. Concatenating numeric and non-numeric data just to specify units seems like the wrong way to go. I don't use Boost, so if that is something boost does, then I go with the implementation, but I can't see the value in it.